# Uncertainty with instances in navigation: UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, multiple-instances

In my app, I have a `UITabBarController` that is set as the initial view controller and has the storyboard ID '*TabBarControl*'. *TabBarControl* has 4 tabs, and off of the second tab(**index 1**) there is a sequence of `UIViewController` navigations that goes as such, where VC is `ViewController`..

`UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController`('*branchesControl*') > VC1('*branchesView*') > `UINavigationController` > VC2 > `UINavigationController` > VC3 > `UINavigationController` > VC4

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` named '*Confirm*' on the navigation bar in VC4. The *Confirm* button triggers the following IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)confirmClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //EXECUTE NAVIGATION
    UITabBarController * tabControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
    tabControl.selectedIndex = 1;

    [self presentViewController:tabControl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The goal is to navigate from VC4 back to the original '*branchesView*'

The problem is, I've noticed that a manual set of a color of a UIBarButtonItem on VC2's navbar resets to a default white after hitting *Confirm* and then revisiting the view stack. I believe that I am creating multiple instances.

How can I simply navigate back to *branchesView*, and then VC2 without creating new instances?

**PS** I'm not sure if the new instance is *TabBarController* or *or branchesView*, I just know that it would seem that I am creating multiple instances somehow with the `confirmClicked:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going back to the existing `branchesView`, you are presenting a new `UITabBarController` with a whole new set of child view controllers which is almost certainly not what you want to be doing.

Instead, you need to pop back to the already existing view controller that you want to get back to. You can do this either by reference or index, and in your case, by simply popping to the root (provided the view controller you want to get to is indeed at the root).

You can simply do:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Your question also makes it seem like each view controller in the stack is wrapped in a new navigation controller. if that is the case, you will need to fix that as well. You should not nest `UINavigationControllers`. Instead, have a single one as the root for each tab and each time you want to push a new `UIViewController` onto the stack, you call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToPush animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you. Most helpful answer I've gotten in a long time. Tell me, would it be alright to just be using segues instead of `pushViewController:` every time to navigate forward? And you're suggesting to just leave *branchesControl* and rid all other `UINavigationController`'s?

Comment: That should be fine, yes. And yes, only a single `UINavigationController` per tab, and get rid of the others.

Comment: Awesome, I'm not sure why but that has always confused me.

Comment: I recommend reading the [UINavigationController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController) and [UITabBarController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarController). They have some pictures and diagrams that could help you wrap your mind around the hierarchies in these components.

Comment: I have read both of them entirely.. they just haven't really made sense to me reading them now or in the past, I'm losing my `NavBar`'s when trying to remove the `UINavigationController`s.

Comment: At this point you should ask a new question and post code specific to the issue you're facing.